# JavaScript Glib.spawn_async stdout file descriptor

Tags: javascript, python, glib, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I want to spawn a process using spawn_async in the GLib bindings in javascript in a gnome3 shell-extension.

I need something like the "standard_output=True" parameter in the python doc http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html which, when enabled, returns a filedescriptor to stdout of the process. The python API and C API differ heavily in this point.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any precise documentation of the JS API to GTK anywhere, the official page doesn't even list it though the shell is written in js to big parts...

The background of my question is that I call a python script doing serial communication, since I saw no other way to let JS get its data from such a script but through spawning a process.

Do you have any guess how to get the stdout of a process started like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pygobject documentation you referenced is for the static libraries. Since Seed works through GObject introspection, you're safer trusting the C documentation. (Seed is the GObject introspecting Java Script library)

Perhaps you can roll your own function that does what you want in C and expose it to Seed: http://developer.gnome.org/seed/stable/seed-Native-Functions.html

Comment: I still don't quite know how to embed the c code I've written now in my shell-extension

Comment: ok solved, the doc is still not very serchable and well linked... placed my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This page includes info about http://developer.gnome.org/seed/3.0/seed-Modules.html embedding/utilizing your "c-module" in the javascript. An example taken from the page:

```
hello = imports.hello;
hello.say_hello_to("Tim");
```